# Oracle insert value into a column with power

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I insert a value into a column with power? Please see the below example:

[image]

Can it be done via the UNISTR function?

```
insert into table values ('2332239 12'); -- I intentionally want to insert the number into a varchar field.
```

Comment: I want to insert a text string with a value in power as a postfix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean you want to insert a string that ends with Unicode superscript 12 you can just put Unicode characters in a Unicode string and insert them into a Unicode column:

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES(N'123¹²')
```

(Your column will have to be an NVARCHAR)

If your column is a varchar and you can't change it you'll have to encode the data somehow, and decode it  very time you want to use it (not ideal)